# Xamarin Errors with android emulator

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I run my android emulator but i have the following issues

[image]

I downloaded the API 19 for the Kitkat android 4.4.
Apparently it has to do with libaries but I dont kow how to fix them, nothing is found on google.